# "Invalid CFML construct found" in Framework/1 core file

Tags: coldfusion, fw1

I downloaded Framework/1 from [RIAforge](http://fw1.riaforge.org/) and browsed to it.
I'm getting the following error:

> Invalid CFML construct found on line 46 at column 81.
>
> ColdFusion was looking at the following text:
>
> [
>
> The CFML compiler was processing:
>
> ```
>    A script statement beginning with public on line 46, column 9.
> ```
>
> The error occurred in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FW1\org\corfield\framework.cfc: line 46
>
> 44 :   }
>
> 45 :
>
> 46 :   public void function addRoute(

I'm using cf9.0.0.25.1028

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Framework/1's newest version, 2.x requires ColdFusion 9.0.1 at a minimum, which you don't have (thanks for posting your exact version - great question asking skills!). Just update your server and you will be set.

If you need ColdFusion 8 and 9.0.0 suppport, FW/1 version 1.2 is still a great piece of software and will work on your existing server.